# Is there any generics version of apache common object pool?

Tags: java, apache-commons, objectpool, apache-commons-pool

When using [apache common pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/), it can provide me a good implementation of Java object pooling. However their [KeyedPoolableObjectFactory](http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.5.6/org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedPoolableObjectFactory.html) interface is not type safe. Is there any object pool library in Java that can provide a generics interface for us to create a type safe object pool?

Comment: Sure you really need an object pool? In which context are you going to use it?

Comment: To hold a list of client information and a list of topic listener of AMQ. Hopefully, the client entry can be evicted after idle a period of time.

Answer (score 5):

Apache Commons Pool version 1.6 supports generics

http://commons.apache.org/pool/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know, but it's easy enough to create a typed wrapper around the commons-pool implementation, so your calling code can use generics.

Comment: Is is not so easy. For example, the following is not possible.
    public class X<T> implements GenericKeyedObjectPool {
    @Override
    public void activateObject(final Object arg0, final Object arg1) throws Exception {
    if (arg0 instanceof T)
    .... => error
    }

Comment: Or I can only use this, but it is not so good for creating the required object.

    public class X<T> implements KeyedPoolableObjectFactory {
    private Class<T> type;
    public static <T> X<T> create(Class<T> type) {
    return new X<T>(type);
    }

Comment: @raymond Why artbristol means it that you can create a class which holds an instance of `KeyedObjectPool`. Then you are free to define your own API, delegating calls to the referenced `KeyedObjectPool`. See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_%28Entwurfsmuster%29 for more details on how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks artbristol and Helper Method. It seems that I have no other choice at this moment but to implement a wrapper or adaptor to achieve this. :)